# How can I play an audio file at specified times in JavaScript AudioContext?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, arraybuffer, audiocontext

How can I play an audio file at specified times in JavaScript AudioContext ?

```
    const context = new AudioContext();
    const source = context.createBufferSource();
    const audioBuffer = await fetch('./Sound.wav')
      .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
      .then(ArrayBuffer => context.decodeAudioData(ArrayBuffer));

    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(1,3,5,7,20,30,40); // I want to play many times this file at these seconds. (Sound.wav length is 1second)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AudioBufferSourceNode#start()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start) method accepts optionals *offset* and *duration* parameters in seconds as its second and third params (the first one being the usual *when* to start playing).

However you can start such a node only once (even though you can make it loop). So you will have to create a new node every time you want to start playing your audio file. But don't worry, these nodes have an extremely small footprint and won't eat your memory.

```js
(async () => {
  const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/transcoded/d/dc/Strawberry_Fields_Forever_%28Beatles_song_-_sample%29.ogg/Strawberry_Fields_Forever_%28Beatles_song_-_sample%29.ogg.mp3";
  const context = new AudioContext();
  const audioBuffer = await fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
    .then(buffer => context.decodeAudioData(buffer));

  const play = (startTime, duration) => {
    const source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(context.currentTime, startTime, duration);
  };

  [1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 18].forEach((startTime) => {
    const btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.onclick = (evt) => play(startTime, 1);
    btn.textContent = "start at " + startTime + "s";
    document.body.append(btn);
  });
})().catch(console.error)
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kaiido to your help , in fact I want to play an audio file (metronome sound ) for mutiple times at exact times to create a metronome.
my metronome sound file length is 1second and i want to play this file below the main music that has 1'34 minutes length as a metronome.

Comment: Then it's the first argument "when to play"